# In d3.js, enter() selection is not empty when re-adding same data to a selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have found a behavior in d3.js v5 that I do not quite understand. It is most easily explained with a short example: 
First, I create a new element on an empty html page, in this case a paragraph:

```
d3.selectAll("body").selectAll("p")
  .data([null])
  .enter()
  .append("p");
```

This creates a single new paragraph element. Then I select the created element and "update" the data to be the same as before like so:

```
var enterSelection = d3.selectAll("body").selectAll("p")
  .data([null])
  .enter();
```

In my understanding, enterSelection would be an empty selection now because the newly added data is exactly the same as the one already attached to the paragraph selection and, hence, also has the same length. However, enterSelection is not empty.

Am I getting something wrong about how and when enter selections are created? My understanding so far was that an enter selection is only created if the newly added data array is larger than the one already attached to the selection.

**EDIT**

Using `enterSelection.size()` actually yields a size of 0, thanks @Andrew Reid. What had me confused though (and that's the way I originally checked) was the result of

```
d3.selectAll("body").selectAll("p")
  .data([null])
```

in the web inspector, which reads like the following before any paragraph elements exist on the page:

```
Selection {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1), _enter: Array(1), _exit: Array(1)}
  _enter: [Array(1)]
  _exit: [Array(0)]
  _groups: [Array(1)]
  _parents: [body]
  __proto__: Object
```

This had me thinking that both the enter and the exit selection had size 1 when calling the mentioned code snippet *after* the paragraph element was created because in this case it yields:

```
Selection {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1), _enter: Array(1), _exit: Array(1)}
  _enter: [Array(1)]
  _exit: [Array(1)]
  _groups: [Array(1)]
  _parents: [body]
  __proto__: Object
```

However, with closer analysis I found now that

- upon the initial paragraph creation, the `_enter` array in the selection is `[EnterNode]` and the `_exit` array is `[]` whereas
- in the latter case both arrays are actually `[empty]`.

I'm finding it odd that in one case the empty array is displayed as `[]` and in the other case it is displayed as `[empty]`. Is there a deeper meaning to this or should I simply accept it?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate. Using your code I get an empty selection on the second code block. If I log `enterSelection.size()` I get zero, nor do I get a newly appended element if I use enterSelection to append a new p.

Comment: This is indeed an empty selection.

Comment: You haven't provided how you check whether it's empty or not. Try this: `console.log(enterSelection.size())`. You'd see it returns zero for an empty selection.

Comment: @Andrew Reid Thanks for the hint! I updated my question as I found that I was *actually* confused because the array ```[empty]``` is displayed as array of size 1 in my web inspector.